# Send radio button value to PHP from form

Tags: php, html

Trying to learn how to do an autocomplete. I have the following in my html file (the code pasting function won't work so I have an image:

[image: html code]

Between the head tags I have the following function:

```
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.post("autocomplete_script.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
} // lookup
```

I want to send the value of the checked radio button to autocomplete_script.php so I can do an if else within the php. I can't find any examples that are helping me, I though this would be an easy one. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

form.serialize() function gets all the data from the form, then you send it to the autocomplete_script.php, your lookup script looks something like this.

```
function lookup(inputString) {
    if(inputString.length == 0) {
        // Hide the suggestion box.
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
        url:'autocomplete_script.php',
        type:'POST', 
        data:$("form").serialize(),
       success:function(data)
       {
              //SUCCESS do your thing, response as data
           }
    });
    }

} // lookup
```

Hope It Helps

Comment: Not sure how I access the string in my textbox when the form values are sent to the php file. The id of my textbox is "inputString".

Comment: Seralize takes all the things just use $_GET['inputString'] in the php